# Need php mysql stats chart example script

Tags: php, mysql, statistics, charts

Does anyone know where can i get php chart script (example) something like this http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/808/chartg.png/, its necessary that it should have timeline (below). Grateful for any help

Answer (score 2):

http://www.ebrueggeman.com/phpgraphlib/

you should use Google

Comment: 'you should not ask subjective questions' - Absolutely don't agree. Many questions & answers are subjective, just look at the most famous questions. Moreover, many answers you may feel objective are subjective. And last but not least, the ultimate thing is whether the answer helps, not whether it is (sub/ob)jective!

Comment: BTW, the phpgraphlib looks exactly like jpgraph! Isn't it a fork of jpgraph? I wouldn't be suprised as it seems to me jpgraph got little worse...

Comment: @TomasTelensky: not it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

I use [jpGraph](http://jpgraph.net/), simple and fast:

look for sample code at:

http://jpgraph.net/download/manuals/chunkhtml/ch15.html#id2553962

Answer (score -1):

I use jpgraph.

--
crap because of SO: body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 14

Comment: duplicate of **corretge** answer